# Queue.Clone method usage C#

Tags: c#, queue, clone

I have found the following solutions [Clone function in the documentation on MSDN for the Queue class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.clone(v=vs.110).aspx).
But in my code, i get the following error:

```
private Queue<int> myQueue = new Queue<int>();
var clone = myQueue.Clone();
```

> 'System.Collections.Generic.Queue' does not contain a definition for 'Clone' and no extension method 'Clone' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Queue' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How can I use this function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Clone` is available for old, non-generic `Queue` class.

With generic Queue you can do:

```
var copy = new Queue<T>(oldQueue)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing two different types:
[`System.Collections.Queue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.aspx) and [`System.Collections.Generic.Queue<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx)

The second one (which you are using) doesn't have a `Clone` method.